# Objection.js: Can all where clauses be enclosed in parentheses after they have been added?

Tags: node.js, orm, query-builder, objection.js

Code example

```js
// Creates an Objection query. 
// I have no control over the creation of the query. I can only modify the query after it has been created.
// Example: "select `todos`.* from `todos` where `text` = ?"
const objectionQuery = thirdPartyService.createQuery(userControlledInput);
// Adds an access check. Example "select `todos`.* from `todos` where `text` = ? and `userId` = ?"
objectionQuery.andWhere("userId", currentUser.id);
```

The above example has a security bug. If the `thirdPartyService` generates a query like this:

```sql
select `todos`.* from `todos` where `text` = ? or `id` = ?
```

Then after adding the access check we will get the following query:

```sql
select `todos`.* from `todos` where `text` = ? or `id` = ? and `userId` = ?
```

And this query can return data that doesn't belong to the current user.
To fix this bug, we need to enclose the user-controlled conditions in parentheses:

```sql
select `todos`.* from `todos` where (`text` = ? or `id` = ?) and `userId` = ?
```

**But how do I do this with the Objection query builder?** I imagine something like this:

```js
const objectionQuery = thirdPartyService.createQuery(userControlledInput);
wrapWhereClauses(objectionQuery);
objectionQuery.andWhere("userId", currentUser.id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to wrap the original query to be subquery / temporary table:

```
MyModel.query().from(thirdPartyService.createQuery(userControlledInput)).where(...)
```

(please let me know if this works at all, I haven't tested it)

Comment: Yeah, it works and creates a query like this: `select * from (select `todos`.* from `todos` where `text` = ?) where `userId` = ?`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From [docs](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/precedence-and-parentheses.html): You can add parentheses to queries by passing a function to any of the `where*` methods:

```js
await Todo.query()
  .where('userId', 1)
  .where(builder => {
    builder.where('text', 2).orWhere('id', 3);
  });
```

will result in

```sql
select * from "todos" where "userId" = 1 and ("text" = 2 or "id" = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have no control over the creation of the query. I can only modify the query after it has been created. So I cannot use your solution.